# Background is not getting executed for the below code. scenario outline is executing properly

Tags: selenium, maven, zoho, feature-file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpvrX.png)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv0kC.png

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to execute the @CreatingLead scenario. The 2 lines which are part of "Background " is not executed but all the other steps are executed. Could u plz check

Comment: I think you should check the menus at the top. Whether 'Leads' menu exists in there. Or it is in the ellipsis menu. As it is usually sorted based on recently used modules.